# bash while loop failing while using sed

Tags: sed, while-loop

I am facing an issue with `sed` in a while-loop.using sed. I want to read the 2nd column of `file1`, compare it with the content of `file2`, and if the string is matched, i want to replace the matched string of `file1` with `file2` string.

I tried with the following code, but it is not returning any output.

```
cat file1 | while read a b; do
  sed -i "s/$b/$(grep $b file2)/g" file1 > file3;
done
```

**Example input:**

`file_1` content:

```
1 1234
2 8765
```

`file2` content:

```
12345
34567
87654
```

**Expected output:**

```
1 12345
2 87654
```

Comment: You are preforming inplace edits with `sed`. This does not return any output. So `file1` is updated on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

Your script is very inefficient. Using the while-loop you read each line of `file1`. This is *N* operations. Per line you process with the while loop, you reproscess the full `file1`, making it an `N*N` process. However, in the sed, you grep `file2` constantly. If `file2` has `M` lines, this becomes an `N*N*M` process. This is very inefficient.

On top of that there are some issues:

- You updated `file1` inplace because you use the `-i` flag. An inplace update does not provide any output, so `file3` will be empty.
- You are reading `file1` with the while-loop and at the same time you update `file1` with `sed`. I don't know how this will react, but I don't believe it is healthy.
- If `$b` is not in `file2` you would, according to your logic, have a line with only a single column. This is not what you expect.

A fix of your script, would be this:

```
while read -r a b; do
  c=$(grep "$b" file2)
  [[ "$c" == "" ]] || echo "$a $c"
done < file1 > file3
```

which is still not efficient, but it is already `M*N`. The best way is using `awk`

---

**note:** as a novice, always parse your script with http://www.shellcheck.net
**note:** as a professional, always parse your script with http://www.shellcheck.net

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$1;next} {for(i in a){if(match($0,"^"i)){print a[i],$0;continue}}}'  file1  file2
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution:

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$2]=$1
  next
}
{
  for(i in a){
    if(match($0,"^"i)){
      print a[i],$0
      continue
    }
  }
}
'  Input_file1  Input_file2
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                             ##Starting awk code from here.
FNR==NR{                          ##Checking condition if FNR==NR then do following.
  a[$2]=$1                        ##Creating array a whose index is $2 and value is $1.
  next                            ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{                                 ##Statements from here will run for 2nd Input_file only.
  for(i in a){                    ##Traversing through array a all elements here.
    if(match($0,"^"i)){           ##Checking condition if current line matches index of current item from array a then do following.
      print a[i],$0               ##Printing array a whose index is i and current line here.
      continue                    ##Again take cursor to for loop.
    }
  }
}
'  Input_file1  Input_file2       ##Mentioning all Input_file names here.
```